# Unable to get a JSON response from my express router using node-Fetch module

Tags: angularjs, node.js, api, express, mean-stack

So I'm making a post request to my Express search router where I'm using the node-fetch module to call a remote api:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

router.route('/search')
    //Performs Job Search
    .post(function(req, res){

        var area = req.body.area;

        fetch('https://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=*********&l=' + area)
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            console.log(json);
        });
    })
```

I'm using angular 1 on the client side to call the router and parse the returned json:

```
  $scope.search = function(){
      $http.post('/api/search', $scope.newSearch).success(function(data){
      if(data.state == 'success'){
        //perform JSON parsing here
      }
      else{
        $scope.error_message = data.message;
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm just starting out with the MEAN stack and only have a vague idea of how promises work. So my issue is that my angular search function is not getting the JSON string I want to return from my remote API call. But rather the data parameter is getting set to my page html. Eventually the breakpoints I've set in the .then() clauses are hit and my json is returned. So my question is how can I use Anguular to get the JSON values when they are finally returned????

Comment: Your post function doesn't return a response. Shouldn't you have `res.send(json)` in your second `then` statement?

Comment: When I set a breakpoints in my .post function it goes to the end of the function and then returns to the client  before either of the then functions are hit. Eventually the breakpoint in my .then functions is hit and returned but not really sure where as my angular function has already ran to completion.  I tried your solution and I got the following error:  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Ah, you already have res.json in there. So you don't need res.send.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
router.route('/search')
    //Performs Job Search
    .post(function(req, res){

        var area = req.body.area;

        fetch('https://api.indeed.com/ads/apisearch?publisher=*********&l=' + area)
        .then(function(result) {
            res.json(result);
            //or possibly res.send(result), depending on what indeed responds with
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had forgotten that I had middleware in place where if the user was not authenticated when performing the search they were redirected to the login page. So I was getting a bunch of html returned for this login page, rather then my json. What still confuses me is why my breakpoints in search function were ever hit if I was being redirected before ever reaching this function.